# Unable to run firefox for different user in Ubuntu 22.04: cgroup error

Tags: firefox, snap, 22.04, cgroup

Just installed Ubuntu 22.04 here, and I get this error while trying to run a firefox instance for an user which is not the one who logged into X. Here's the full command trace to reproduce the error, typed in a `gnome-terminal` session:

```
me@mypc:~$ sudo adduser www
[sudo] password for me: 
Adding user `www' ...
Adding new group `www' (1002) ...
Adding new user `www' (1002) with group `www' ...
Creating home directory `/home/www' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD: The password is a palindrome
Retype new password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for www
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
    Full Name []: 
    Room Number []: 
    Work Phone []: 
    Home Phone []: 
    Other []: 
Is the information correct? [Y/n] 
me@mypc:~$ xhost +
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
me@mypc su - www
Password: 
www@mypc:~$ export DISPLAY=:1
www@mypc:~$ firefox 
/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-org.gnome.Terminal.slice/vte-spawn-00e5cd03-e354-4ba8-aca7-2245c0e8b1cb.scope is not a snap cgroup
www@mypc:~$
```

Note that `1000` is the uid of the user `me`.

Note that if switch to console with `ctrl+f3`, log in with user `www` and run `DISPLAY=:1 firefox`, than the browser correctly opens in display 1. So there must be something related to the terminal.

Comment: After few days of using Ubuntu 22.04, I come to the conclusion that snap sucks; it's terrible in a single user environment, and it's impossible to use in a multi-user/single-X-session environment. Solution is just to completely remove the snap version and use the good old atp package